# What is the default insertion order in zend lucene index?

Tags: zend-framework, lucene, insertion

I'm building an application that need to bring the posibility to navigate trough one index or more (without a query).

When i was inserting documents on index i thought that they were be available on the same order that was been inserted, but it isn't like that. Even if i insert only in one field numerical values or its alphanumeric representations.

I thought that getting the documents (1, 2, 3, 10, 14, 28, 56, 57) with something like:

```
for($x=0;$x<$index->maxDoc();$x++){
   echo $index->getDocument($x)->IDfield."<br>";
}
```

... i wold get 1, 2, 3, 10, 14, 28, 56, 57... right?, but it doesn't happen. I get something like 57, 1, 28, 2, 10, 3, 14, 56... and that's my question. Is there a default order on insertion?

Answer (score 0):

Your best friend in figuring this out is going to the Lucene source code. You will find a default order, but it may not be to your liking.

By the way, why do you need to navigate through an index without a query? (Maybe there is a different way to approach your problem.)